# Javascript lock css change display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I whant do do a few css changes to single element in single script, but I whant all the changes displayed at once. For example :

```
$("#someelement").css({width:"100%"}); //this change should not be displayed
$("#someelement").width($("#someelement").width()-$("#somelement #child").width());
//in this case i have a problem to count #child's width if it depends on #someelement's width
```

In this sceneario I only get to calculate element's max width by setting it to 100% before. But i don't whant that change to be visible for user, i only whant `$("#someelement").width($("#someelement")-$("#somelement #child").width());` to be applied. Is there a way to lock and unlock user interface for a while?

As i understand browser renders whenever the box model changes, now there's the question, how can i prevent that and stack more changes until browser flush them?

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle?

Comment: I faced this problem once, and if I remember well when you change the width of an element, get the width, and the change it back to the value it was before, there is no visible change. I'm not an jQuery expert, but as far as I remember jQuery doesn't not "flush" css modification immediately.

Comment: @ôkio is there a way to controll css flushing?

Comment: Take a look here : http://www.phpied.com/rendering-repaint-reflowrelayout-restyle/

Comment: As i understand browser renders whenever the box model changes, now there's the question, how can i prevent that and stack more changes until browser flush them?

Comment: The hell is this? $("#someelement")-$("#somelement #child").width()

are you subtracting element and an string/float????? 
$("#someelement") returns an element.

Comment: @Mr.TK it's not hell, it's a typo, hoever the concept of the question should be clear anyway

Comment: You wanna change an element's `width` but dont want it to be visible for user?

Comment: Yes, up to some point

Comment: Then store the calculated widths in an array then apply em whenever u like em to be applied

Comment: @BatuZet well that's the problem, those element's width have dependecy some sort of dependencies, to get #child's width that i need, i have to make #somelement 100%.. This may sound confusing, but if i could pick between storing their values and changing browser's flow controll, i would pick to change flow controll

Comment: Well i guess you need to get the elements width in pxs when it's set to 100%. That width is also can be calculated by getting its `parent`'s width because that's what element's width gonna become when it's set to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//$("#someelement").css({width:"100%"}); // youre not gonna need this
$("#someelement").width($("#someelement").parent().width() - $("#somelement #child").width());
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say but this has nothing to do with answering this question